# How can I install wordpress within a wordpress

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm having some troubles with wordpress.
In the server I have wordpress installed in the public_html folder and I wanted to create another site for it.

Lets say I have the www.example.com website on public_html
Where should I install another wordpress files to have www.example.com/course
I've checked several sites and forums for help on this but I can't create a multisite platform because the page is more than a month old and I don't want to screw everything up..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just upload a new Wordpress installation to any subfolder. It will be a completely seperate site and will also need it's own database. So your folder structure would be similar to this:

new-wordpress <-- New folder with wordpress files

wp-admin

wp-includes

wp-content

...Wordpress Files...

**EDIT:**

You can use the same database but I don't think you would want to. Any chagnes you make on either the old or the new will affect both the old and the new. If you are trying to make a copy of the site the you can:

1. copy your current wordpress files into that new folder
2. make a dump of the oringinal database and import that into a new one
3. update the database info in the wp-config file and then run a script
   to update the new database to use the new URL. You can use a script like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ to do this.

.

Comment: Can I use the db of the original site?

Comment: You can but I wouldn't. I added more info in the answer.

Comment: Okay! I'll try that and create the db. I'll select the answerd in a bit. Thanks a bunch. If any problem comes up I'll tell you.